# Keras LSTM - Input shape for time series prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to predict the output of a function. (Eventually it will be multi input multi output) but for now just to get the mechanics right I am trying to predict the output of `sin` function. My dataset is as follows,

```
    t0          t1
0   0.000000    0.125333
1   0.125333    0.248690
2   0.248690    0.368125
3   0.368125    0.481754
4   0.481754    0.587785
5   0.587785    0.684547
6   0.684547    0.770513
7   0.770513    0.844328
8   0.844328    0.904827
9   0.904827    0.951057
.....
```

Total of 100 values. `t0` is the current input `t1` is the next output I want to predict. Then data is split into train/test via scikit,

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(wave["t0"].values, wave["t1"].values, test_size=0.20)
```

Problem happens in fit, I get an error that says input wrong dimensions.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=??? ,stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
          batch_size=10, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I've tried other questions on the site to fix the problem but no matter what i try i can not get keras to recognize correct input.

Comment: What are the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: @thushv89, x_train is column t0, y_train is column t1

Comment: @thushv89 numpy array of single values

Comment: Think that's where your problem is. The `LSTM` layer accepts an input of `[batch_size, sequence_length, num_features]` input. So you will need to reshape your input to `[1,100,1]` array.

Comment: @thushv89, that part i understood from other questions but how to do and what does it look like after reshape i can not get my head around.

Comment: Which reshaping are you referring to ? And still don't understand which part you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The LSTM expects the input data to be of shape (batch_size, time_steps, num_features). In sine-wave prediction, the num_features is 1, the time_steps is how many previous time-points the LSTM should use for prediction. In the example below, batch size is 1, time_steps is 2 and num_features is 1.

```
x_train = np.ones((1,2,1)) 
y_train = np.ones((1,1))

x_test = np.ones((1,2,1))
y_test = np.ones((1,1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(2,1)))
#for stateful
#model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(1,2,1), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=1, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: You dataset woks fine. How ever when i try to reshape my data, `x_train = x_train.reshape((1, x_train.shape[0], 1))` I still end up with the same error. Original x_train is (80,) and reshaped is (1, 80, 1). `Error when checking input: expected lstm_7_input to have shape (2, 1) but got array with shape (80, 1)`

Comment: you need to change the input_shape, appropriately like this: model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(80,1))).